# Background will not display in html page using css

Tags: html, css, background

When I open my web page my background will not come up only a white screen

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content= "Jaime-Lee McClelland"/>
<style>
 body {
    background:  url('background_desk.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 500px: margain: 40px auto;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue      Light", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; font-size: 62.5%; font-weight: 300;    color:#000; text-align: center;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: That is probably not the whole of your webpage, but just in case: if the <body> is absent (or, empty), its height will be 0 and no background will be shown.

Comment: Also, you have errors in your CSS. `margain` should be `margin` and there should be only one space in `"Helvetica Neue Light"`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the path to your background image. If the image isn't in the same folder as your HTML file, it will not work with the code you posted above.

Also, you have a typo in margin (you have margain) which could also be causing an issue. This is presuming your page is complete (meaning you have a closing style tag, opening and closing body tags, and then close the open HTML tag).

[This resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files) may help you learn about file paths and folder structure for websites. [This resource](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) should help with CSS backgrounds.